# Курсор для бд postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Прошу помощи с написанием курсора на postgresSQL - есть такое задание

Хранимая процедура для расчета успеваемости и прироста успеваемости
Хранимая процедура имеет два параметра определяющие анализируемый интервал времени. Результатом работы процедуры должна явится выборка, содержащая средний бал по всем предметам в рассматриваемом интервале времени, и разницу текущего среднего балла и предыдущего.

Алгоритм реализации предлагается следующий. Организуется курсор, перебирающий все года, в которых проводилось обучение, попадающие в заданный интервал времени. Средний бал предыдущего года запоминается в переменной. В теле курсора формируется выборка необходимых данных.

Переписываю с MySQL на postgresSQL и ничего не работает, как исправить подскажите...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."Student_UP_UPp"(
date_begin character varying(50),
date_end character varying(50))
RETURNS record
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

 AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
avg_prew real = 0;
avg_now real = 0;
 tempp character varying(50);
 done integer = 0;

 cur CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT AVG("MARKS"."VALUE"), "GROUPS"."NAME"
  FROM "PEOPLE", "MARKS", "GROUPS"

 WHERE "PEOPLE"."ID" = "MARKS"."STUDENT_ID" 
 AND "PEOPLE"."GROUP_ID" = "GROUPS"."ID" 
 AND RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4)
 BETWEEN date_begin AND date_end
 GROUP BY RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4) ORDER BY 
 RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1; - проблема с этой 
строкой

SELECT AVG("MARKS"."VALUE"), "GROUPS"."NAME"
FROM "PEOPLE", "MARKS", "GROUPS"
WHERE "PEOPLE"."ID" = "MARKS"."STUDENT_ID" 
AND "PEOPLE"."GROUP_ID" = "GROUPS"."ID" 
AND RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4)
BETWEEN date_begin AND date_end
GROUP BY RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4), "GROUPS"."ID" ORDER BY 
RIGHT("GROUPS"."NAME", 4); 

BEGIN
Open cur;
 repeat   равно ли это такой строке в постгрес-> LOOP 
 FETCH cur INTO avg_now, tempp;
  IF NOT done THEN
 SELECT avg_now-avg_prew;
  SET avg_prew=avg_now;
 END IF;

 until done 
 end repeat; = ли это такой строке в постгрес-> EXIT WHEN NOT done; 
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Вызываю через

```
  SELECT public."Student_UP_UPp"('2016', '2017')
```

Изначальный код на MYSQL

```
 create procedure student_up(IN date_begin char(50), IN date_end char(50))
  begin
  declare avg_prew float default 0;
  declare avg_now float default 0;
 declare temp char(50);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
   select avg(marks.value), groups.name
      from people, marks, groups
  where people.id = marks.student_id and people.group_id = groups.id and 
  right(groups.name, 4) between date_begin and date_end
   group by right(groups.name, 4) order by right(groups.name, 4);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
  select avg(marks.value), groups.name
  from people, marks, groups
  where people.id = marks.student_id and people.group_id = groups.id and 
  right(groups.name, 4) between date_begin and date_end
 group by right(groups.name, 4) order by right(groups.name, 4);
 Open cur;
 repeat
 FETCH cur INTO avg_now, temp;
   IF NOT done THEN
 select avg_now - avg_prew;
   set avg_prew = avg_now;
  end if;
  until done end repeat;
   close cur;
   END
  call student_up("2015","2018");
    drop procedure if exists student_up;
```

Comment: в postgresql нет обработчиков, которые бы надо было объявлять заранее. так что уберите тот declare. Что касается прерывания цикла, то после fetch делаете `EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;`. И да, цикл должен начинаться loop. Лучше примеры посмотрите, все таки весь синтаксис pl/sql сильно отличается от mysql. например http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/

Comment: А еще у вас строка `select avg_now - avg_prew;` даст ошибку. в select должно быть указано откуда он выбирает и в pl/sql вдобавок КУДА он выдает результат. можно например в переменную сохранить. А вот вернуть выборку из хранимой процедуры, как это делается в mysql в принципе не возможно. Так что данное вам задание не применимо к postgresql "_Результатом работы процедуры должна явится выборка_" - результатом работы процедуры postgesql не может быть выборка. Может быть временная таблица или скажем массив или открытый курсор, но не выборка

Comment: Печально, мне надо бы сделать это, да и пускай бы возвращало в виде таблицы записей... А это еще через питон надо запускать, а тут оказалось вот оно как

Comment: Я думал это учебное задание, из за этого и курсор. Я не вникал в происходящее, но если вам нужен именно результат, то процедура не нужна. любые данные можно получить одним запросом, без всяких курсоров. Особенно, учитывая, что это postgesql и тут есть оконные функции, на подобии lag/lead дающие данные из предыдущей/следующей строки

Comment: Увы, это учебное задание, и тут задача как раз использовать курсор, но  мне не приходилось с ним сталкиваться поэтому и обратился сюда. Так то это понятно, что через разные типы запросов с подзапросами все это возможно реализовать

Comment: Тогда интересно что за препод, который просит что бы процедура postgresql вернула выборку. Вот если бы нужна была функция, а не процедура и можно было бы из нее потом сделать select, тогда другое дело, возврат таблицы из функции с использованием табличного типа и return next, очень даже реально. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27663197/5669174

Comment: Вообще  это ряд заданий и скорее всего, когда их писали, не думали о конкретном выборе БД (любая БД, хоть в exel ) поэтому слегка странно и звучит, а так, я через функцию postgresql  и делаю, увидел, что курсор там можно реализовать, да и потом это что-то близкое к mysql процедуре, но как оказалось - то что работает в mysql не работает в постгрес напрямую

Comment: Вам надо разобраться, что же в MySQL делает DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER, и понять, как написать аналогичное на plpgsql заново. Очевидно, там совсем другие операторы. А вообще итерирование по результатам курсора очень легко: FOR _rec IN FETCH ALL FROM "cursor_name" LOOP (...тут код внутренностей цикла...) END LOOP; Здесь _rec - переменная типа record.